# calculating a time complexity of this code

Tags: time, time-complexity

can someone explain to me how i can calculate time complexity of h3(worst case) here...
 given this code :

```
int g3(int n) {
  if (n <= 1)
    return 2;
  int goo = g3(n / 2);
  return goo * goo; //i have trouble with this line`
}

int h3(int n) {
  return g3(g3(n)); //trouble with this one too
}
```

i've tried to calculate the complexity based on what i calculated it's Big O of nlog(n) , however it's wrong ...
is there a quick and technical method to solve these kinds of problems fast and correctly ?
(I usually use recursive tree method to calculate time complexity)

Comment: `goo*goo` is just integer multiplication

Comment: Can you tell what the time complexity is ?i  still get nlog n using the tree

Comment: ok i think ive figured it out

Answer (score 0):

g3 have O(log n) complexity, n is divided by 2 in all the values of n, the result is a logarithmic function. h3 have O(log n), and this is because complexity depends on function g3, doesnt matter the function composition in the return value g(g(n)) and the value of n, the key is the g function complexity. The algorithm needs use all values of n and do something logarithmic to give the n*logn complexity

Comment: i got O of n (, time complexity of f3 is a composition of logn and log(2^n) )